# Should I trust mysql that delete all rows that I ask?

Tags: mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, sql-delete

I can't find an answer for my question. I hope I won't make a duplicate.

So, let's say I have exactly 10 rows with `row_parent_id = 3`.

It is possible that mysql, on command `DELETE FROM table WHERE row_parent_id = 3`, to delete **only** 9 rows because ... an error on mysql?

If yes, if some error can occur and the query will delete only 9 rows, then that means **I must count rows before** any delete action?

If no, then I can trust mysql?

PS: I'm using PDO and prepared statements. I just don't understand if is necessary to count rows before delete. I want to make sure all rows are deleted as I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that MySQL's InnoDB storage engine supports [atomic operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)). Atomic in the sense of cannot-be-split-any-further, not in the sense of atomic bombs.

This means if the DELETE succeeds, it means it deleted *all* matching rows. There's no partial success. If it only deleted 9 rows, that means only 9 matching rows were visible to your transaction.

In InnoDB, if the DELETE is interrupted or encounters an error, all the rows it had deleted so far are automatically restored; none are deleted.

MyISAM does not support atomic operations. The DELETE can be interrupted while it is working through the rows to be deleted. So it might delete fewer rows than it was supposed to—and they're really deleted. No rollback is possible.

This is an important reason why you should not use MyISAM!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist 9 rows deletion even though there is an error on some row , you can do it like as you said. You can count the rows before DELETE operation and you can get the number of rows affected by `PDOStatement::rowCount( void )` after the operation.

But if you want to catch the exception and never delete any row if there is an error occured, well you can do it like that :

```
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, false );
$pdo->beginTransaction();
try{
    $pdo->exec("DELETE FROM table WHERE row_parent_id = 3");
    $pdo->commit();
}catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "exception occured !";
}
```

About your last question never trust MySQL about manipulating rows. You can always get errors like `constraint violations` etc.

Comment: I'm using transactions and I also check for errors with a catch block like in your example. Anyway, in your opinion, I should count before delete. I'm still waiting more opinions.Thanks for your answer!